# Hibernate loads entire database when accessing Map collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, collections

I have these two tables:

```
Foo(
  ID INT PK
)

FooDate(
  FOO_ID INT PK,
  DATE DATETIME PK,
  VALUE DECIMAL
)
```

and I have these classes for mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @MapKeyTemporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @MapKey(name = "date")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
    private Map<Date, FooDate> fooDate = new HashMap<>();
}

@Entity
public class FooDate implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FooDateId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)     
    private Foo foo;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DATE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")    
    private BigDecimal value;
}

@Embeddable
public class FooDateId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "FOO_ID")
    private Integer foo;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private Date date;
}
```

The `FooDate` has tons of data

When I try to put a new value to the `Map`, Hibernate loads the entire database.

The same happens when I try to save a `foo` instance.

```
Foo foo = dao.get(1);
foo.fooDate.put(new Date(), new BigDecimal()); //fetch all records

dao.merge(fundo); // same when saving the new value
```

Is there a way to query just for the `Date` that I'm trying to insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Hibernate, you can try Hibernate specific [extra lazy collections](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/hibernate-extra-lazy-collection-fetching):

```
@MapKeyTemporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@MapKey(name = "date")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
private Map<Date, FooDate> fooDate = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: and is the poster using Hibernate?!

Comment: @NeilStockton Thanks for the remark, I edited my question accordingly.